# DynamoDB GSI BatchGetItem

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, amazon-dynamodb-streams

Is it possible to retrieve rows from the dynamodb Global secondary index using batchgetitem api? If my aim is to retrieve data from the main table based on some non-key attribute also , but data should be retrieved in the batch of 100 items - is the GSI index won't fit here?

Also is BatchItemGet API available for Query? Say a table has the primary key and sort key and same primary key can have multiple sort keys can I retrieve multiple primary keys using batchItemGet with just primary key only or it won't fir here?

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to specify the index name in the `BatchGetItem` API operation according to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html). That means using `BatchGetItem` (and `GetItem` for that matter) on a secondary index isn't possible. Both of these operate on the primary index.

If you want to retrieve data from a secondary index, you need to use `Query` or `Scan`. Both support the `IndexName` attribute according to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html). When using `Query` you have to specify the partition key and can optionally filter based on the sort key. If you don't filter on the sort key, you will get all items with the partition key, which should take care of your second requirement.

To retrieve data from a secondary index based on different partition keys, you'd need to issue multiple `Query` operations for the separate values of these keys, there is no batching here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PartiQL with `WHERE IN` clause for that:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderID IN [100, 300, 234]
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.select.html

Comment: With PartiQL The `IN` clause is limited to 100 values or 8192 characters.  It's a little bit of trial and error to find the limits.

Comment: The `WHERE IN` clause limit appears to be 50 values if you're using a secondary index. It's not clear where these can be found in the documentation and it may largely depend on how the PartiQL gets translated into Dynamo queries.